# Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string' with React Redux Slice

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript with React and Redux and I'm trying to explore TS as much so I can learn it, but I'm getting this error: `Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const desktopSlice = createSlice({
    name: "desktop",
    initialState: {
        desktop: "none",
    },
    reducers: {
        save: (state, param) => {
            const { payload } = param;
            state.desktop = [...state.desktop, payload];
        },
    }
});
const { actions, reducer } = desktopSlice
export const { save } = actions;
export default reducer;
```

Comment: Seems like `desktop` should be a string but you're assigning an array to it. I don't know which of the two is correct - should it be an array or should you be assigning a string. If the latter, it's unclear what string is expected. You have not explained what *should* happen here.

Comment: And what if it is both?

Comment: Then that's also something you've not explained. All in all you said you have an error. It's clear what the error *is*, it's entirely unclear what the solution is supposed to be.

Comment: So if the value is an string then changes to an array latter when data changes

Comment: you're not even telling us what line is triggering the error. The error is pretty clear, so you simply need to understand why the type of the left hand side of the assignment is `string` and why the right hand side is `any[]` and figure out what is being done wrong. The type safety is doing its job here! If you're learning, then trace the typing of each of the elements (LHS and RHS) of the faulty assignment.